# What is the difference of Office 365 Share Point online and Share Point 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Forgive me I just a newbie for SharePoint world. Recently I just sign up a trial version of it from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn766173(v=office.15).aspx) try to learn development of APP. But What make me confused is I saw a lot of names for Share Point.

Some of them are :

1.Share Point 2013 Online.

2.Office 365 SharePoint Online.

3.SharePoint 2013 On-Premise.

4.SharePoint 2013.

5.Office 365 Development Site.

Is there difference between them? I also don't know if it is right choice to get start with Development site to learn Share Point. Please give me some advice or right direction to make it .
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There two big things.

1. **SharePoint On-Premise**

When you install SharePoint on your hardware( servers) on your intranet(virtual hosted environment) using the your Active Directory. Data remains within you, you have full control on authentication, Server side customization, full control on environment from logs to central admin and full range of services applications access(depend upon the license). But to get this level of control you have to pay for extra, OS server license, SQL Server license and SharePoint License. If you are small company then this is big cost. You also need to worry about updating(CU / SP) your farm.

1. **[SharePoint Online( Office 365)](http://www.office365answers.com/AllArticles/ID/2341/What-is-Office-365.aspx).**

Office 365 is a subscription-based online office and software plus services suite which offers access to various services and software built around the Microsoft Office platform.
which included hosted versions of Exchange, Lync, SharePoint, Office Web Apps etc.

SharePoint Online is one component of Office 365.I always called SharePoint online is subset of SharePoint on Premise. You will get only part of the services online version but cost effective way( as compare to on-premise). You don't need to worry about the patching the farm as MSFT regularly update it, No Need to worry about uptime / optimization as MSFT taking care of it. SSL offered by default. No server side customization, You have to relay on the Client Side.

The Microsoft [SharePoint Online Developer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh147180(v=office.14).aspx) Guide is designed to help you gain knowledge and understanding of SharePoint Online within Microsoft Office 365 as you build and extend your online sites to meet your business needs.

Now check below link to get complete comparison of features.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-service-description.aspx

http://blog.technovert.com/2014/02/sharepoint-2013-online-vs-premise-its-time-call/